# The nearest lower possible value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
struct StreamInfo
{
    public Stream Stream {get; set;}
    public Quality Quality {get; set;}
}

public enum Quality
{
    VeryLow,
    Low,
    Medium,
    High,
    Maximum,
}
List<StreamInfo> streamInfos;

private Stream NearestLowerPossibleValue(Quality quality)
{
    ....
}
```

I have List of struct `StreamInfo`  with `Stream` and `PhotoQuality`. I need function which pick nearest possible value from the set. This mean, if I have in list `StreamInfo` with qualities `Low`, `Medium`, `Maximum`. And I call `NearestLowerPossibleValue(Quality.High)` I need get stream with Medium quality, because High missing, if there be High I want get stream with High quality. I am looking some nice solutions, because I did not invent any nice solution. Thank for your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Stream NearestLowerPossibleValue(Quality preferedQuality)
{
    var streamInfoWithHigherQualityThanPreferred = streamInfos.Where(i => i.Quality <= preferedQuality);
    var mostSimilarToPreferred = streamInfoWithHigherQualityThanPreferred.MaxBy(i => i.Quality);
    return mostSimilarToPreferred.Stream;
}
```

Throws exceptions if streamInfos is null or empty or if streamInfos contains no elements which are less or equal to preferedQuality. I use function MaxBy from [nuget package MoreLing](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), but if you can not add this package you can use:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        return source.MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (selector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        }
        if (comparer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
        }
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
            }
            TSource current = enumerator.Current;
            TKey y = selector(current);
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource arg = enumerator.Current;
                TKey x = selector(arg);
                if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
                {
                    current = arg;
                    y = x;
                }
            }
            return current;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Quality
{
    VeryLow=1,
    Low=2,
    Medium=3,
    High=4,
    Maximum=5,
}

private PhotoQuality NearestLowerPossibleValue(PhotoQuality quality)
{
   int lenny = (int)quality;
   if (lenny != 1) lenny--;
   return (PhotoQuality)lenny;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I need something like this
if (streamInfos.ContansStreamInfoWithValue(Quality.High)
    return streamInfos.First(i => i.Quality == Quality.High);
else if (streamInfos.ContansStreamInfoWithValue(Quality.Medium)
    return streamInfos.First(i => i.Quality == Quality.Medium);

Comment: @Lenny - that is not english

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know formatting not working in comments

Comment: @Lenny - modify your question.  You don't define streamInfos in your question so there is no way to answer your question or know what the heck you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the `StreamInfo` structure, I'll suggest you to implement the `IComparable` interface:

```
struct StreamInfo : IComparable<StreamInfo>
{
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
    public PhotoQuality Quality { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(StreamInfo other)
    {
        return Quality - other.Quality;
    }
}

public enum PhotoQuality
{
    VeryLow,
    Low,
    Medium,
    High,
    Maximum,
}
List<StreamInfo> streamInfos;

private Stream NearestLowerPossibleValue(PhotoQuality quality)
{
    return streamInfos.Where(si => si.Quality <= quality).Max().Stream;
}
```

If not, we are always able to use the `Aggregate` method:

```
private Stream NearestLowerPossibleValue(PhotoQuality quality)
{
    return streamInfos.Where(si => si.Quality <= quality)
        .Aggregate((si1, si2) => si1.Quality > si2.Quality ? si1 : si2).Stream;
}
```

Comment: Having a custom `IComparer<T>` works as well if `StreamInfo` is not extensible.

Answer (score -1):

Taking advantage of integer values of enums:

```
public enum Quality
{
    VeryLow,
    Low,
    Medium,
    High,
    Maximum,
}

IEnumerable<Quality> qualities = new List<Quality>
{
    Quality.Low,
    Quality.Medium,
    Quality.Maximum
};

Quality preferedQuality = Quality.High;

Quality actualQuality = qualities
    .TakeWhile(quality => quality <= preferedQuality) // arrow phun
    .Max(); // will throw if qualities is empty

Assert.AreEqual(Quality.Medium, actualQuality);
```